# Add extra column in insert with instead of trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

EDIT 1:Basically I want to do 
INSERT INTO Users(col1, col2, col3)   when Users only have col1 and col2 , col3 doesn't exist.

I have a table **UsersAddresses** with two int fields "User" and "Addresses" which that binds my table **Users** to another table **Addresses**. I need to audit any change made to my user so I have a trigger on my Users that works fine, any changes made to my Users table creates a line in the audit table.

The problem is that I also need to trigger the same trigger if I add an addresses to my user. So I create a trigger on my UsersAddresses that will do an update of the Users table. But I need to have the modifierId aswell (to know who wanted to make this change) So I figure out I should alter the way I insert in UsersAddresses to add this Id. I've tried the following, adding a fake "ModifierId" but as expected I get "invalid column name" when I try to add this trigger.
Do you know what I should do ?

Thankfully

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateUser 
ON [dbo].[UsersAddresses] 
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS
DECLARE @User INT;
DECLARE @Address INT;
DECLARE @ModifierId INT;

SELECT @User = [User] FROM inserted;
SELECT @Address = [Address] FROM inserted;
SELECT @ModifierId = [ModifierId] FROM inserted;

INSERT INTO [UsersAddresses]([User], [Address])
VALUES (@User, @Address);

UPDATE [Users]
SET [CreatorId] = @ModifierId
WHERE [Id] = @User;
```

Edit Solution: Credits to [Michael](http://blogs.msmvps.com/p3net/author/p3net/)
use context_info with a procedure.:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsersAddresses] (
    [User]    INT NOT NULL,
    [Address] INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_UsersAddresses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([User] ASC, [Address] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ToUser] FOREIGN KEY ([User]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ToAddress] FOREIGN KEY ([Address]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Addresses] ([Id])
);



GO
CREATE TRIGGER [ChangeToUsersAddresses]
    ON [dbo].[UsersAddresses]
    FOR DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
    IF ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted) > 1)
      THROW 51000, 'To many records', 1

     DECLARE @UserId INT;
     IF (SELECT [User] FROM inserted) IS NOT NULL
     SELECT @UserId = [User] FROM inserted
     ELSE 
     SELECT @UserId = [User] FROM deleted
     INSERT INTO [Audit_Users](UserId,ActiveDirectory,FirstName,LastName,Type,Status,ModifierId,Date)
     SELECT [Id], [ActiveDirectory], [FirstName], [LastName], [Type], [Status], [dbo].GetUserContext(), GETDATE()
      FROM [dbo].[Users] WHERE [Id] = @UserId

  INSERT INTO [Audit_UsersAddresses]([User], [Address])
  SELECT @@IDENTITY, [Address]
  FROM [UsersAddresses]
  WHERE [User] = @UserId;

END;
```

GetUserContext() that is used in the insert :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetUserContext] ()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN COALESCE(CONVERT(INT, CONTEXT_INFO()), 0)
END
```

And Finally the procedure to set the context.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetUserContext]
    @userId INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @context VARBINARY(128)
    SET @context = CONVERT(BINARY(128), @userId)

    SET CONTEXT_INFO @context
END
```

Comment: Your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. It assume there will only ever be one row in inserted. You need to write setbased code in your trigger and assume there are multiple rows in inserted. You have to remember that triggers in sql server fire once per operation, not once per row.

Comment: Yeah I  know about that but Its not the issue right now (plus the database is only queried by my wcf services and they will query only one row at a time)

Comment: That is the wrong to think about your data. If you don't do it right the first time when are you going to schedule the time to go rewrite it? The rewrite won't happen. It does not take any longer to write triggers correctly and avoid this issue.

Comment: Well I'm doing a POC right know, I need to know if it's possible to pass "parameters" to insert this way or another, or I will have no trigger at all, I'm not going to implement it this way but I find it easier to understand the concept this way first. I'm really new to databases

Comment: What doesn't look correct to me is why do you want to update the users table when somebody inserts a UserAddress? Isn't the CreatorID the ID of the person who created the UserAddress? Seems to me that updating your audit columns is like rewriting history.

Comment: Yes you can use parameters in an insert statement. Syntactically I don't see anything wrong with your trigger.

Comment: Well  Updating CreatorId field of Users doesn't do any change to this Row but triggers an insert in Audit_Users and take this field for "ModifierId". 
I could just do the same with UserAddresses and add a column "ModifierId" , Just in order to have this parameter but I'd really like to do the same without adding a column

Comment: "Invalid column name 'ModifierId'".  That's what's wrong in my syntax, because ModifierId doesn't exist in UsersAddresses It won't create my trigger

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79971/discussion-between-lomithrani-and-sean-lange).

Comment: You could replace @ModifierID with SUSER_SNAME()

Comment: what is "fake ModifierId", are you saying this column does not exist in table User?  Also, could you just log the change to the same audit table, as opposed to trying to update User table?

Comment: @TabAlleman Could I do that with entity framework ? Change SUSER_SNAME() at will ?  Because I will have only one connection with the database, my wcf service is going to do all the queries. But if I could change SUSER_SNAME from the wcf service then I would have the behavior I wich to have.

Comment: @Greg It doesn't exist in UserAddresses, no . I want to be able to call lets say "INSERT INTO [UserAddresses](User, Addresses, TempVar) VALUES (myUser, myAddress, modifierId)"   But UserAddresses only have 2 column

Comment: I've never used entity framework, but with any kind of front end, I would pass the username as a parameter from the front end.

Comment: Then you need to add that column to the table in order to insert into it!!!!

Comment: @Greg I know but I wanted to find a work around. I went for the best solution imho and went for context_info and a procedure to set that context_info I'm able to call the procedure from my app to set the ID and then I use the context_info in the trigger.